# MATLAB extract files with certain extension from a folder

Tags: matlab, directory, filenames

How to extract all the files with certain extension giving the name of the directory and the extension without changing the current directory?

I have looked into `dir` but this only search current directory and its subfolders, it does not take a certain directory as an argument. Same thing with `ls` command. My `MATLAB` info is a bit rusty. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a folder and an extension in [`dir`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) as follows. Let

```
folder = 'c:\users\Luis';
extension = 'txt';
```

### Search in a folder

To display the results on screen:

```
dir([folder filesep '*.' extension])
```

To obtain a cell array of strings with the matching file names:

```
d = dir([folder filesep '*.' extension]);
filenames = {d.name};
```

### Search in a folder and subfolders recursively

According to the [documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html), use a double wildcard:

```
dir([folder filesep '**' filesep '*.' extension])
```

or

```
d = dir([folder filesep '**' filesep '*.' extension]);
filenames = {d.name};
```

Comment: Do you mean search in subfolders recursively?

Comment: Recursion was added to `dir` in R2016b

Comment: Thanks, @excaza. I didn't know that (for recursion I normally use `fileattrib`, but this is more flexible). Edited answer